# How to access a JSON string's values in a React component that have been sent from a server?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring-boot, fetch, state

I have a React component, Profile, that uses a path variable and props to grab the user id from the path variable, which is then used to send a POST request to the server to retrieve a user's data in the form of a JSON object:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "username": "ss",
    "password": "$2a$10$7cN2vQa5VeaAvBNjX5y.0OmVWpH7Rz.sDvuugbMUEtzNJGW63argS",
    "name": "Sam",
    "email": null,
}
```

This is then saved to a state variable:

```
componentDidMount(){

  fetch(GET_SINGLE_USER_URL + this.props.match.params.id, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Authorization": localStorage.getItem("token")
            },
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => this.setState({user: data}));
```

}

I want to be able to get the value of the username from the 'user' state using this.state.user within the rest of the componentDidMount() function, so I can use it to send another POST request to get the user's profile image, requiring the username.

When I try:

```
const imgUrl = USER_IMG_URL + this.state.user[0];
```

OR

```
const imgUrl = USER_IMG_URL + this.state.user.username;
```

within the componentDidMount() function and then try to console.log it only prints the user img url with 'undefined' concatenated:

```
/image-files/undefined
```

I could create another controller method in the ImageFileController to handle the id and use that to find the username and then call the same service, but this seems bad practice as I'd have duplicate code?

Also, in the render() method:

```
render() {
        const {user, img, isLoading} = this.state;

        console.log(this.props.location);
        console.log("USER:");
        console.log(user);
```

}

The user prints fine, so it's definitely been saved to the state.

Edit:

Would this work?

```
componentDidMount() {
        
        let user = '';
        
        const imgUrl = USER_IMG_URL + user.get("username");
        
        
        fetch(GET_SINGLE_USER_URL + this.props.match.params.id, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Authorization": localStorage.getItem("token")
            },
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => this.setState({user: data}))
            .then(data => user += data);
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

In react, setting state is asynchronous. so if you set state in componentDidMount and try to access it in same function, there is no guarantee that you will get value from state. But once state is set and try to get in render method you will get it.

So if you want to get the value and do another call from componentDidMount, use data from server

try something like below

```
componentDidMount() {        
     Code to do API call
    .then(data => {
        this.setState({user: data});
        const imgUrl = USER_IMG_URL + data.username;
        <use imgUrl>
    });
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response, I have edited the question with my implementation of what you say, would that work? Thanks.

Comment: It still just says undefined, even when i move the const imgUrl = USER_IMG_URL + user.get("username"); below the fetch. thanks.

Comment: you have to move image related activity once you receive data of user.
.then(data => this.setState({user: data})). after this try const imgUrl = USER_IMG_URL + user.username. Inside "then" of promise, you can try

Comment: So move everything else into a different function? Which function? Thanks.

Comment: not to move to another function. You will get data from server in "then" function of promise. From there you can trigger the second API to get image

Comment: But it's already in the 'then' function no?

Comment: Update my answer with some sample code. Can you check?